# How to Set value to th element inside the tfoot

Tags: javascript

This might be simple question but i am not able to solve it,I want to set value to `th` element inside `tfoot` Section see the below image

[image]

and below is code

```
$('#'+tableId+" tfoot tr").each(function(i, object) {   
    $(this).find('th').each(function(j){
        //How to set value to th        
    });
});
```

How to set the value to `th`.Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the value, it's text content:

```
$('#'+tableId+" tfoot tr").each(function(i, object) {   
    $(this).find('th').each(function(j){
        $(this).text('Some text');
    });
});
```

you just need to decide to what text (or HTML) to set content to.